# Cumulative sum of columns in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to sum across variables

```
N1 N2 N3
1  1  1
1  .  1
1  1  .
```

Want

```
N1 N2 N3 B1 B2 B3
1  1  1  1  2  3
1  .  1  1  1  2
1  1  .  1  2  2
```

The array that I am trying looks like not working at all..

```
data temp2; 
    set temp; 
    array hh(*) N:; 
    array bb(3); 
    do i=1 to dim(hh);
        bb(i)=bb(i)+hh(i+1);
    end; 
run;
```

I dont want to use transpose and cumulate the sum.

Answer (score 0):

**First, you have an error in your algorithm**: a cumulated value

- should not be calculated from itself an the next input value,
- but from the previous cumulated value and the corresponding input value.

You rather need `bb(i) = bb(i-1) + hh(i)`. Of course, this does not work when `i` is 1 because there is no `hh(0)`, so you start doing this from `i` = 2 on.

**Second, you need to handle missing values**, something like a `coalesce` in SQL. Let us use `ifn` for that, a function that returns a numeric variable. The first argument is a condition, the second is the return value if the condition is true, the third the value the returnvale if the condition is false.

**Putting it all together**;

```
data AFTER;
    set TEMP;
    array hh(*) N:; 
    array bb(3); 

    bb1 = ifn(missing(N1), 0, N1);
    do i=2 to 3;
        bb(i) = bb(i-1) + ifn(missing(hh(i)), 0, hh(i));
    end; 

    drop i;
run;
```

**The down side of this sollution** is the hardcoded 3 in `array bb(3)` and `do i=2 to 3`, which user3658367 tryed to solve with `dim(hh)`. Unfortunately, that only works for one of them.

**So this is better**;

```
proc sql; 
    select count(*) 
      into :B_count 
      from sasHelp.vColumn 
     where libname eq 'WORK'
       and memName eq 'TEMP'
       and name like 'N%';
quit;

data AFTER;
    set TEMP;
    array hh(*) N:; 
    array bb(&B_count); 

    bb1 = ifn(missing(N1), 0, N1);
    do i=2 to &B_count;
        bb(i) = bb(i-1) + ifn(missing(hh(i)), 0, hh(i));
    end; 

    drop i;
run;
```

**I added** the condition `name like 'N%'` because I assume in your real live problem TEMP has other variable than the once you are cummulating.

**About the comments below** : if you were not involved in this post from the start, you can neglect them. I included them in the text above.

(To the autors of these comments: thanks for your input.)

Comment: This works only half., when there is a missing value it stops there and doesnt carry the value. so the output becomes


    N1 N2 N3 B1 B2 B3
    1  1  1  1  2  3
    1  .  1  1  
    1  1  .  1  2

Comment: `array bb(3);` does NOT define **temporary** variables. It defines regular variables named `BB1` to `BB3`.  If they had not been defined before then they will be numeric. If they have already been defined in the step then they need to have consistent type. To make temporary variables you need to add the `_temporary_` keyword to the `array` statement.

Comment: Why did you attach the `8.` format to the variables B1-B3?

Comment: Thanks for your remarks, I will integrate them and test the code this weekend.

Comment: Change `bb(i) = bb(i-1) + hh(i)` to use the SUM() function to handle the missing values.

Comment: Good remark. I did not do so, because `bb1 = sum(0, N1);` looks a little silly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very comfortable with arrays, so I would use a macro to do the work.

```
data temp;
input N1 N2 N3;
datalines;
1 1 1
1 . 1
1 1 .
;
run;

options mprint mlogic;

proc sql;
select name into:cols separated by ','
from dictionary.columns
where libname = upcase("work") and memname = upcase("temp") and upcase(name) like 'N%';
quit;

%macro cumul_colsum;

data temp2;
set temp;
run;

%do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(%superq(cols)));

%let var = %scan(%superq(cols),&i,%str(,)); %put |&var|;

data temp2;
set temp2;
B&i. = sum(of N1-&var.);
run;

%end;
%mend cumul_colsum; %cumul_colsum;
```

And get the desired result, which in this case is the one OP requires. I have used the `like 'N%'` same as Dirk to feed the column names to a macro, and a do loop to create the columns with cumulative sums. This might take a while for huge datasets. But it's just easier to understand (`options mprint nonotes;`) what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

follow @Reeza suggestion of using sum instead of + for handing missing values. something like below.

```
data have;
input
N1 N2 N3;
datalines;
1  1  1
1  .  1
1  1  .
;

data temp2; 
set have; 
array hh(*) N1 N2 N3; 

array bb(3) b1 b2 B3; 
do i= 1 to dim(hh);
if i= 1 then bb(i) = hh(i);
 else   bb(i)= sum(bb(i-1),hh(i));
end; 
drop i;
```

run;